# Why doesn't my layout match up with Google's Material Design Guidelines?

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

I am trying to follow Google's Design Guidelines while designing my app. I want to create a single-line list, and I am following the guidelines on [this page](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/lists.html#lists-specs) for a *Text Only Single-line list.*

Here are the specifications:

```
Font: Roboto Regular 16sp
Tile height: 48dp
Text padding, top: 16dp
Text padding, bottom: 20dp

Bottom padding is measured from the baseline.
```

and the picture which also shows left and right padding:

[image: Single-line list]

Here is the result I'm getting after following the specs:

[image: My Result]

As you can see, it gets cut off. Who is in the wrong? Here is my layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Single-line item"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I tried removing the `android:textAppearance` line, but it only changed the color of the text.

What's wrong here? Why doesn't my layout match up with Google's guidelines?

Comment: I think the issue is in the `Bottom padding is measured from the baseline`. I would consider simply using the top padding

Comment: @njzk2 Alright, that's what I'll do. I was just confused why it didn't seem to be working when I thought I was following the design guidelines correctly.

Answer (score 0):

There's really no need for you to specify padding in this case. The parent layout has a fixed height, so you can simply make the TextView wrap its content and center it vertically in its parent.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Single-line item"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In general, I only use padding when I actually need to shift the content of a view by some amount. Most for the time though, proper layout parameters (alignment, gravity, margins, etc) are enough.